# Always show hover text in an appropriate position

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a hover effect over a textarea: when the mouse is over the area, I want to display a text `Available in Apple Store` in the center. Here is the HTML code:

```
<section class="apps">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="media">
        <div class="app">
          <div class="content">
            ...
          </div><!-- content -->
        </div><!-- app -->
        <div class="media__body">
          <br>
          <a class="btn btn-lg btn-theme" target="_blank" href="www.google.fr">Available in Apple Store</a>
        </div>
      </div><!-- media -->
    </div><!-- row -->
  </div><!-- contaniner -->
</section>
```

And here is the CSS: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qapoja/4/edit?html,css,output).

As you can see, with different width of the screen, the text `Available in Apple Store` is not always in a good position; when the screen is very narrow, just a part of this text can be shown (I would want it to be wrapped).

Does anyone know how to amend this?

PS: is it possible to make the button always **vertically** centered?

Comment: You could use flex box to position it in the center. https://www.kirupa.com/html5/centering_vertically_horizontally.htm And as @Roberrrt mentioned make your button width is taken care of to prevent text overflow. Cheers.

Comment: This would still result in overflowing when OP wants to add more text to a button..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood the question correctly, you want the .btn to be centred and to wrap if it's too long?

If that's the case you can add this code to your CSS.

```
.apps .media__body a.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

**Here's a demo:**

```css
.apps {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 80px 0;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.apps .app {
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  border-top: 1px solid #75C181;
  border-left: 1px solid #75C181;
  border-right: 1px solid #75C181;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #75C181;
}
.apps .app .content {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.apps .media {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.apps .media__body {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  transition: 0.6s;
}
.apps .media__body:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}
.apps .media__body:after,
.apps .media__body:before {
  bottom: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s 0.2s;
  transition: 0.6s 0.2s;
}
.apps .media__body:before {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  left: 2em;
  right: 2em;
}
.apps .media__body:after {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  bottom: 2em;
  top: 2em;
}
.apps .media__body:hover:after,
.apps .media__body:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
.apps .media__body h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.apps .media__body p {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}
.apps .media__body a.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: #fff;
}
.apps .btn-theme {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="apps">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="media">
        <div class="app">
          <div class="content">
            Proin scelerisque magna ac eros aliquam aliquam id in lacus. Morbi quam tortor, consequat at orci non, vulputate volutpat libero. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean sagittis laoreet urna eu ornare.
            Aenean tempor, leo vel eleifend porttitor. Aenean tempor, leo vel eleifend porttitor, nibh libero ultricies est.
          </div>
          <!-- content -->
        </div>
        <!-- app -->
        <div class="media__body">
          <a class="btn btn-lg btn-theme" target="_blank" href="www.google.fr">Available in Apple Store</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- media -->
    </div>
    <!-- row -->
  </div>
  <!-- contaniner -->
</section>
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

`.apps .media__body` has got some padding, remove that and it will work across all sizes.

Comment: OK... that works... a little detail: sometimes when the screen is large enough, the text `Available in Apple Store` is still displayed in 2 lines. Is there any setting to limit **less** the width of this text?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line of `CSS` to your button:

```
.btn {
    white-space: pre-wrap
}
```

This makes sure the text gets wrapped when exceeding boundaries.

Comment: is it possible to make the button always vertically centered?

Comment: Isabel's solution would work fine with that, but let me check if I can write the required code.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to achieve this, just use the following lines for your `btn-theme` class:

```
 position:relative;
 top:50%;
 transform:translateY(-50%);
```

Comment: @Roberrrt what do you mean? This should work on any size screen.